# jQuery Getting uploaded image's name

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

```js
//Picture upload
$(function() {
  $(":file").change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

```html
<form id="form_roomtype" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top: 57px;" action="roomtype" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" id="current_roomtype_id" name="current_roomtype_id" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="roomtype_id_to_remove" name="roomtype_id_to_remove" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="chk_tarif_applicable" name="chk_tarif_applicable" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="photo_name" name="photo_name">

  <div>
    <span style="font-size: 16.85px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #757575;">ROOM PICTURE</span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br/>

    <img id="myImg" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/insert_images.png" alt="room image" height="175" width="285" onclick="file" />
    <br />Destination:
    <input type="text" value="C:\Project\Booking_Engine\Java\booking\src\main\webapp\data" name="destination" />
    </br>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to take the id of the input (#file) and assign it to the hidden input with id (#photo_name) using the picture upload js on top.

I need to take the id of (`<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />`) and assign it to the id of (`<input type="hidden" id="photo_name" name="photo_name">`).

I already have the JS that I posted before... I need to use it to do the assigning of id.

I already have the id of the input file though the JS... (this.file[0]) already gives me the name of the uploaded files... now what I need is take this name and assign it to the id of the hidden input.

---

I need the value of photo_name in my java code below:

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    String currentRoomTypeIdStr = request.getParameter("current_roomtype_id");
    Integer currentRoomTypeId = Integer.valueOf(currentRoomTypeIdStr);

    String photoName = request.getParameter("photo_name");
```

if (!Objects.equals(currentRoomTypeId, null) || !Objects.equals(roomtypeIdToRemove, null)) {
            try {
                mUserTransaction.begin();

```
            if (currentRoomTypeId == 0) { // Add mode
                ChambreTypeEntity typeChambreEntity = new ChambreTypeEntity();
                typeChambreEntity.setLibelle(inputTypeRoom);
                typeChambreEntity.setCode(inputCodeRoom);
                typeChambreEntity.setDescription(inputDescriptionRoom);
                typeChambreEntity.setNbMinPers(inputMinPerson);
                typeChambreEntity.setNbMaxPers(inputMaxPerson);
                typeChambreEntity.setNbEnfGratuit(inputChild);
                mEntityManager.persist(typeChambreEntity);


                ChambrePhotoEntity chambrePhotoEntity = new ChambrePhotoEntity();
                chambrePhotoEntity.setNomPhoto(photoName);
                chambrePhotoEntity.setTypeChambre(currentRoomTypeId);
                mEntityManager.persist(chambrePhotoEntity);

            }
            else { // Modification mode
                Query query = mEntityManager.createQuery("FROM ChambreTypeEntity WHERE id=:pId")
                        .setParameter("pId", currentRoomTypeId);
                List<ChambreTypeEntity> typeChambreEntityList = query.getResultList();
                if (!typeChambreEntityList.isEmpty()) {
                    ChambreTypeEntity typeChambreEntity = typeChambreEntityList.get(0);
                    typeChambreEntity.setLibelle(inputTypeRoom);
                    typeChambreEntity.setCode(inputCodeRoom);
                    typeChambreEntity.setDescription(inputDescriptionRoom);
                    typeChambreEntity.setNbMinPers(inputMinPerson);
                    typeChambreEntity.setNbMaxPers(inputMaxPerson);
                    typeChambreEntity.setNbEnfGratuit(inputChild);
                    mEntityManager.persist(typeChambreEntity);
                    mEntityManager.persist(chambreTypeTarifTypeEntity);

                    ChambrePhotoEntity chambrePhotoEntity = new ChambrePhotoEntity();
                    chambrePhotoEntity.setNomPhoto(photoName);
                    chambrePhotoEntity.setTypeChambre(currentRoomTypeId);
                    mEntityManager.persist(chambrePhotoEntity);


                }
            }
            mUserTransaction.commit();
        }
```

But right now the value of photo_name is "". I need it to be the value that i chose while doing the picture selection.

Comment: sorry... can you clarify what you are looking for

Comment: i need to take the id of (<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />) and assign it to the id of (<input type="hidden" id="photo_name" name="photo_name">)

I already have the js that i posted before...I need to use it to do the assigning of id

I alerady have the id of the input file though the JS... (this.file[0] already gives me the name of the uploaded files...now what i need is take this name and assign it to the id of the hidden input

Comment: You want the ids to be swapped after the image is loaded?

Comment: yes exactly @AswinRamakrishnan

Comment: You want the file name / name of the image to be the `value` of  `photo_name`?

Comment: yes @AswinRamakrishnan . I have updated my post. I will then need this id to be used in my java code.

Comment: Ok.. I've updated the answer. Let me know if that is what you're looking for. Once the file changes, the name of the file gets set as `photo_name`'s `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following is what you're looking for?

```js
//Picture upload
$(function() {
  // This is a better way of selecting the input field
  $("input[name^=file]").change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

      // This is what you should do
      $('#photo_name').val(this.files[0].name);
    }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_roomtype" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top: 57px;" action="roomtype" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" id="current_roomtype_id" name="current_roomtype_id" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="roomtype_id_to_remove" name="roomtype_id_to_remove" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="chk_tarif_applicable" name="chk_tarif_applicable" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="photo_name" name="photo_name">

  <div>
    <span style="font-size: 16.85px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #757575;">ROOM PICTURE</span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br/>

    <img id="myImg" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/insert_images.png" alt="room image" height="175" width="285" onclick="file" />
    <br />Destination:
    <input type="text" value="C:\Project\Booking_Engine\Java\booking\src\main\webapp\data" name="destination" />
    </br>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No, its not working. I think i'm not explaining clearly. I will edit my question.

My apologies about that.

Comment: here is what is returned when using the code you provided

Current ID of file: file 
New ID of file: photo_name 

Current ID of photo_name: photo_name 
New ID of photo_name: file

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check the value of `photo_name`, once you browse and add a file.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i needed. Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend changing the title to something along the lines of "jQuery Getting uploaded image's name", because the one right now seems misleading. Also, mark it as answer so it'll help others. Thanks!